# What is the hypothesis space used by this AND gate Perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, perceptron

Per this [post](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-30164-8_373)

> The hypothesis space used by a machine learning system is the set of
>   all hypotheses that might possibly be returned by it.

Per this [post](https://medium.com/@stanleydukor/neural-representation-of-and-or-not-xor-and-xnor-logic-gates-perceptron-algorithm-b0275375fea1), the Perceptron algorithm makes prediction

$$
\begin{equation}
  \hat y =
    \begin{cases}
      1 & wx+b >= 0\\
      0 & wx+b<0
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$

> we can conclude that the model to achieve an AND gate, using the
>   Perceptron algorithm is

$x_1 + x_2 – 1.5$

In this case, what is the hypothesis space used by this AND gate Perceptron?

Comment: As far as I understand, the expression $x_1 + x_2 - 1.5 $ which is a model that is capable of mapping inputs to outputs is a hypothesis. There might be more models that can do this action, the whole models are called hypothesis space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand:

A hypothesis is a model which is capable of predicting outputs from inputs, hence the $x_1 + x_2 - 1.5$ is a hypothesis but not the only one. The whole models that have the same capability are regarded as hypothesis space.

We know that in **AND** gate:

```
     x1       x2     output
|---------|--------|--------|
|     0   |    0   |    0   |
|     0   |    1   |    0   |
|     1   |    0   |    0   |
|     1   |    1   |    1   |
|---------------------------|
```

and we have $w .\cdot x + b$, based on which, either $0$ or $1$ turns out as output.
$$w \cdot x + b$$
$$w_1 \cdot x_1 + w_2 \cdot x_2 + b$$

trying all the inputs in this expression:

$w_1 \cdot 0 + w_2 \cdot 0 + b <= 0$ (because the output should be 0)  $b < 0$

$w_1 \cdot 0 + w_2 \cdot 1 + b <= 0$ ---> $ w_2 + b <= 0$  So $w_1 < |b|$

$w_1 \cdot 1 + w_2 \cdot 0 + b <= 0$ ---> $ w_1 + b <= 0$  So $w_2 < |b|$

$w_1 \cdot 1 + w_2 \cdot 1 + b > 0$ ---> $ w_1 + w_2 + b > 0$

---

Firstly, we initialize the weights and bias parameters and then if needed, change them.

Here, since $b < 0$ we set it as $-1$

Since $w_1 < |b|$,  $w_2 < |b|$ and weights are not negative, we set them as 1.
So we would have:

$w_1 \cdot 0 + w_2 \cdot 0 + b = -1 < 0$ is right, returns 0 because is negative.

$w_1 \cdot 0 + w_2 \cdot 1 + b = w_2 + b = 1 - 1 = 0$  wrong, it returns 1 while it should return 0

$w_1 \cdot 1 + w_2 \cdot 0 + b <= 0$ ---> $ w_1 + b <= 0$  So $w_2 < |b|$ wrong, it returns 1 while it should return 0

$w_1 \cdot 1 + w_2 \cdot 1 + b > 0$ ---> $ w_1 + w_2 + b > 0$

So we set b for a smaller value like -1.5 **(Note)**, then all the expressions would work appropriately. Hence $x_1 + x_2 - 1.5$ is a hypothesis for this problem.

**Note**: we know that in using `perceptron algorithm`, when reaching at any point that is not following the current model, weights and bias are updated as follows:

```py
w = w + yx
b = b + y
```

Here, in the source that you referred to, maybe for simplicity they haven't done so and have just found a sample of a plausible model (hypothesis)

The other hypothesizes should follow the previously mentioned rules, thereby, $x_1 + x_2 - 2$ can also be another hypothesis for this problem, etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer. in this specific case, what is exactly the hypothesis space? is it something like $b_{min} < b < b_{max}, \quad and \quad w_{min} < w < w_{max}$. then what is the values of $b_{min}, b_{max}, w_{min}, w_{max}$

Comment: Here the hypothesis space is all forms of w.x+b where are capable of conveying the inputs to outputs correctly.  and based on the expressions like b<0 and w1 < |b| we see that bs and ws are correlated. although, If we follow the perceptron algorithm we would see that b is added by y whenever the condition of the update is true. y here is 0 or 1, hence b equals b + n*1 (n is the number of required updates) for w also, regarding w = w+yx, seemingly, here it can be at most plus 1 because yx is always 0 but in case (1,1)